# Deserialize XML to Object Using Class Decorators ([XmlElement])

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML that looks like this...

```
<SET>
    <ENTITY>
        <HEADER>
            <ELEMENT TYPE = "a"></ELEMENT>
            <ELEMENT TYPE = "b"></ELEMENT>
            <ELEMENT TYPE = "c"></ELEMENT>
        </HEADER>

        <FOO>
            <BAR TYPE = "X">12345</BAR>
        </FOO>
    </ENTITY>

</SET>
```

I know to get the elements or attributes I can do the following:

```
[Serializable()]
[XmlRoot("SET")]
public class Set
{

    [XmlElement("ENTITY")]
    public List<Entity> Entity { get; set; }

}

public class Entity
{
    [XmlElement("FOO")]
    public string Foo; //Returns "12345"

    [XmlAttribute("Type")]
    public string FooType; //returns "X"
}
```

What I need is to be able to return the value for ELEMENT with a type of "B" only. I Do not want "A" or "C"...

Is there some sort of function that can be done like...

```
public class Header
{
    [XmlElement("ELEMENT",Type = "B")] 
    public string Element;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you only want a subset of data, using [Linq2Xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview) can be easier.

Linq:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring);

var xElem = doc.Descendants("ELEMENT")
               .Where(e => e.Attribute("TYPE")?.Value == "b")
               .FirstOrDefault();
```

Xpath:

```
var xElem = doc.XPathSelectElement("//ELEMENT[@TYPE='b']");
```